# React Native: UUIDv4 is not working even after updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uuid

Hey I hope everyone is doing great. I am trying to use uuidv4 but it is not working and throwing different errors. I have tried every possible solution but I am not sure where actually I am doing wrong. Here is some of my code from App.js.

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4();
 const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: uuidv4(), text: 'Milk' },
    { id: uuidv4(), text: 'Eggs' },
    { id: uuidv4(), text: 'Bread' },
    { id: uuidv4(), text: 'juice' },
  ]);
const addItem = (text) => {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return [{ id: uuidv4(), text }, ...prevItems];
    });
  };
<View style={styles.itemsList}>
        <FlatList
          data={items}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem item={item} deleteItem={deleteItem} />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </View>
```

This is what i am getting as an error...

[image]

Here is what AddItem.js looks like

```
const AddItem = ({ addItem }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const onChange = (textValue) => setText(textValue);
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Add Item'
        onChange={onChange}
        style={styles.input}
      ></TextInput>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => addItem(text)}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>
          <Icon name='plus' size={20} />
          Add Item
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Can anybody please help me as i am unable to figure out the possible solution.

Comment: Error message is pretty explicit about whats the problem. It seems you are trying to render an event object in JSX somewhere in your code which is not allowed in JSX.

Comment: I have checked the AddItem.js component but i am still unable to figure out where actually the problem is. Also i have updated that component under the question.

Comment: OnChange will receive a `React.ChangeEvent` and not a `string`. Change it to `const onChange = (event) => setText(event.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

`uuid` library is not working in react-native environment. you should use `react-native-uuid`

```
import uuid from "react-native-uuid";
```

then use it like

```
uuid.v4()
```